# Align divs accordig to the screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to align some divs inside a fullwidth container. These divs will have equal size according to the screen size. Here is a screenshot of what am getting now.

[image]

I need to remove that white space and need to align the divs accordingly.(Am ready to use jQuery codes also.)

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4op9z5k/)

Now am specifying the width of each `div`

Thank you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to get clear idea?

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using for these `<div>`s? It's a little hard to help with so little to go on. Also, which "white space" are your referring to? There's quite a bit in the picture...

Comment: try using bootstrap. It handles all of these

Comment: Bootstrap **might** be of use but it's a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Properly formatted HTML & simple CSS can easily solve this.

Comment: @ flowstoneknight : more white space come when resizing the window. i need to make all divs with equal width according or the window size

Comment: @Paulie_D: am also thinking so. media queries can solve my problem but i want to whether there is any simple solution?

Comment: Are the `<div>`s supposed to all have some set width? Or is the width supposed to change as the window changes?

Comment: Which white space are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media-queries and procentual widths.

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-left: 5px solid pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This makes the blocks floating horizontal. You can now adjust different widths with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) depending on screen sizes.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    width: 15% !important;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2robteh6/

Comment: thank you.But still on resizing have i have problem. i need div to assign some width according to the current window width.

Comment: "Depending on window width" should be procentual, shouldn't it? What rules do you have? Static pixel if window width is greater then X?